# "the public key is not available ..." error upon running sudo apt upgrade after installing Wine

Tags: command-line, apt, upgrade, wine

When I run `sudo apt upgrade`, I get a load of errors than I can't fix:

```
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Hit:3 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                     
Get:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease [8,041 B]       
Err:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease              
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease          
Get:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
W: GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
E: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I installed wine recently and it worked, but at some point recently I tried to run `sudo apt update` and this happened. I have tried to search the problem online and followed the steps but the problem remains. I also tried to uninstall wine, wine32 and wine64 but that didn't work either.

Comment: WineHQ altered their PGP key.  You'll need to follow the steps at [WineHQ's documentation](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) to readd the signing key and make sure the repository uses that key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WineHQ has altered their PGP key. You'll need to follow the steps at [WineHQ's documentation](https://www.winehq.org/Ubuntu) and add the keyrings (at you own risk; external source)

Type this commands to download and add the repository keys:

```bash
sudo mkdir -pm755 /etc/apt/keyrings
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/keyrings/winehq-archive.key https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
```